# CPU low performance

Tags: performance, cpu

I've been using an Asus laptop for almost 3 years. During that time I never had any kind of issues, and every program used to run pretty smoothly.

A few days ago, after patching some Windows updates, my laptop performance significantly decreased. Some games I used to play on average/High settings with 60 fps are now impossible to run, and I'm talking about light games like lol or wow. The Windows 7 processor rating decreased from 6.5 to 5.3 and I'm still wondering why

In the case of World of Warcraft, after uninstalling it, a message pops up when I try installing it again saying my CPU does not meet the minimum requirements.

Would appreciate so much, if anyone could give me some tips in how to solve this problems. I uploaded some pictures:

[image]

[image]

Comment: methinks it's some sort of driver issue like Monkey said.  While it is true that your CPU does not meet the minimum requirements at its BASE frequency, the turboboost frequency is well over that.  My guess is that some Windows update broke the turboboost function somehow.  Maybe look in your BIOS and confirm turboboost is still enabled?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the tool you're using, but it *looks* like it's only reporting 1 core / 2 threads (hyperthreading).  that cpu is 4 core/8 threads, so there's def. something screwy going on with how windows is reading your cpu

Answer (score 0):

Can you figure out exactly what those Windows Updates were?

In either case, it sounds like you might want to re-install your chipset drivers. The Windows Update might have caused some issues with it.

You should download the latest ones directly from Asus or try the Intel website.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I have tryed to download tthe drivers from intel. however a message oped saying it would be unable to instal the drivers because of the asus live update conflicts. but when i check the asus updates it says there are no updates

Comment: @afonsogamboa did you try uninstalling the drivers first and then re-install them? You might not need new drivers but a simple re-install could do the trick